# python most common pair of indices in 3 x n array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, weather

I have a numpy array with shape (3, 600219), which is a list of indices.

i.e.

```
array([[   0,    0,    0, ..., 2879, 2879, 2879],
       [  40,   40,   40, ...,  162,  165,  168],
       [ 249,  250,  251, ...,  195,  196,  198]])
```

The first row are time indices, the second and third rows are indices of the coordinates.  I am trying to figure out which pair of coordinates most frequently occurred, disregarding the time.

e.g. Was it (49,249) or (40,250)...etc.?

Comment: You can do this in O(N^2) by going on each cord and ask how many times it appears in the array. Or you can sort the array some how and than search for the cords, what will do the job in O(N*log(N)) but its a bit more complicated.

Comment: Do you know the maximum coordinate sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used a small sample of your data, but I think you'll get the point:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[   0,    0,    0, 2879, 2879, 2879],
       [  40,   40,   40, 162,  165,  168],
       [ 249,  250,  251, 195,  196,  198]])

# Zip together only the second and third rows
only_coords = zip(array[1,:], array[2,:])

from collections import Counter

Counter(only_coords).most_common()
```

Produces:

```
Out[11]: 
[((40, 249), 1),
 ((165, 196), 1),
 ((162, 195), 1),
 ((168, 198), 1),
 ((40, 251), 1),
 ((40, 250), 1)]
```

Comment: calling `list()` on the zipped rows seems very superfluous as in python2 `zip` already outputs a list and in python3 `zip` returns an iterable which works fine with `Counter` and is much more memory friendly specially in the case of a large dataset

Answer (score 2):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
IDs = a[1].max()+1 + a[2]
unq, idx, count = np.unique(IDs, return_index=1,return_counts=1)
out = a[1:,idx[count.argmax()]]
```

If there could be negative coordinates, use `a[1].max()-a[1].min()+1 + a[2]` to compute `IDs`.

Sample run -

```
In [44]: a
Out[44]: 
array([[8, 3, 6, 6, 8, 5, 1, 6, 6, 5],
       [5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4],
       [8, 2, 3, 3, 8, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3]])

In [47]: IDs = a[1].max()+1 + a[2]

In [48]: unq, idx, count = np.unique(IDs, return_index=1,return_counts=1)

In [49]: a[1:,idx[count.argmax()]]
Out[49]: array([1, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a little abstract, but you could try saving each co-ordinate as a number, e.g. [2,1] = 2.1. And put your data into a list of these co-ordinates. For example, a 2nd row of [1,1,2] and 3rd row of [2,2,1] would be [1.2, 1.2, 2.1] You could then use the code:

```
from collections import Counter
list1=[1.2,1.2,2.1]
data = Counter(list1)
print (data.most_common(1))  # Returns the highest occurring item
```

which prints the most common number, and how many times it occurs, then you can simply convert the number back to a co-ordinate if you need to use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that does the count:

```
import numpy as np
import collections

a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 10, 30 ,40], [25, 25, 10, 50]])
# You don't care about time
b = np.transpose(a[1:])

# convert list items to tuples
c = map(lambda v:tuple(v), b)
collections.Counter(c)
```

The output:

```
Counter({(10, 25): 2, (30, 10): 1, (40, 50): 1})
```